How to convert Cartesian coordinates with relative positions only to geo coordinates
My question:
How can I convert Cartesian coordinates of some points to geo coordinates, knowing the latitude and longitude of only one of the points?
What I want to do, for example:
Converting the following four pairs of cartesian coordinates of a polygon to latitudes and longitudes. (The points were drawn in a CAD software with no geo reference.)
pt_corrds = [
    [11.8721,26.4787],
    [19.489, 48.1805],
    [38.556,41.4878],
    [30.9382,19.786],
]


Problem I'm facing:
The Cartesian coordinates of the points were not converted from any geo-coordinate system in the first place, and they can only tell the positions of the points relative to each other in Meters (...Actually, I only have the latitude and longitude of the first point: [103.63892961184138, 1.3499679811141618].)
What I tried:
I tried the following script based on what's shared here to convert in a brute force way, trying to see what the result might be.
import math

R = 6360000 # earth radius

def xy_to_ll(x, y):
    a = 6378137.0 # WGS84 Semimajor axis
    f = 1/298.257223563 # WGS84 Flatteing
    b = a*(1-f) # Semiminor axis
    z = math.sqrt(b**2*(1-((x**2+y**2)/a**2))) # Solving for the positive z value on the ellipsoid
    p = math.sqrt(x**2+y**2) # Distance from the z-axis
    Lat = math.atan(z/(p*(1-f)**2))*180/math.pi # Solving the latitude value
    Long = math.atan2(y,x)*180/math.pi
    return (Lat, Long)

pt_corrds = [
    [11.8721,26.4787],
    [19.489, 48.1805],
    [38.556,41.4878],
    [30.9382,19.786],
]

for idx in range(4):
    x = pt_corrds[idx][0]
    y = pt_corrds[idx][1]

    lat_lon = xy_to_ll(x, y)
    print('pt ', idx, ':', lat_lon)

What I got is:
pt  0 : (89.99974019715796, 65.85024575234873)
pt  1 : (89.99953468491216, 67.97668039688014)
pt  2 : (89.99949292282923, 47.09766037997194)
pt  3 : (89.99967120806647, 32.6002571572118)

I'm unable to reproduce the polygon based on these four points on geojson.io, which is not surprising because the Cartesian coordinates were not related to any CRS:

What I'm expecting:
I'd like to draw a polygon with the lat&lon as converted for the four points:

